# how to compile glibc on ubuntu 18.04 from source on a different folder

Tags: 18.04, compiling, arm, glibc

I'm trying to virtualize windows 10 arm64 on the jetson nano where I have installed ubuntu 18.04 arm64 (I can't upgrade it to ubuntu 20.04 because nvidia does not support it). To get the best performance I've compiled the latest version of qemu like this :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --target-list=aarch64-softmmu,arm-softmmu --enable-guest-agent --enable-vnc --enable-vnc-jpeg --enable-vnc-png --enable-kvm --enable-spice --enable-sdl --enable-gtk --enable-virglrenderer --enable-opengl
```

(previously I had installed the following packages :

```
apt install libspice-server-dev
apt install gtk+-3.0
apt install libvirglrenderer-dev
```

this is how I run qemu on arm64 :

```
/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt-2.12 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2 -m 2048 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -drive file=/root/Scrivania/Work/win10arm/win10arm.qcow2,if=virtio -nic user,model=virtio -device usb-storage,drive=install -device usb-storage,drive=drivers -drive file="$isoname1",if=none,id=install,media=cdrom,readonly=on -drive file="$virtio",if=none,media=cdrom,readonly=on,id=drivers -bios /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/QEMU_EFI.fd -device ramfb
```

here is the problem :

```
/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64: 

/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28’ not found (required by /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64)
```

as u probably know,ubuntu 18.04 has this old version of glibc :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# ldd --version

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) 2.27
Copyright © 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

So,I need to find a method to upgrade it to 2.28,as requested by qemu 5 or it will not work. I already know that I can't mix the sources of ubuntu 18.04 with the sources of ubuntu 20.04,so I'm looking for a different solution. Maybe trying to compile a new version of glibc from the sources in a different directory than that used by ubuntu 18.04 ?

Answer (score 0):

Glibc is the basis of the entire system, every package built starts with it as its basis. To change it on a distro you need to re-compile every package to use it. Easiest solution is to compile a version of the software released when the 18.04 was current, not try to do new incompatible by years software.

Comment: thanks man. but I don't know what to do pratically with your suggestion. Anyway,do u think that this will not work ? ---> https://ibb.co/hLnKDCk

Comment: The practical is you need to build software meant for your system not newer versions that require a system upgrade.

Comment: I can't. windows arm64 needs qemu 5 to work great. with qemu 4.2 some feature is missing. And I would also like to virtualize Android. To do that,I need to add these parameters to qemu : -device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl=on,xres=1280,yres=720 -display sdl,gl=on ; as u can see,it needs that all the most important features can be activated. I know that I can't use ubuntu 18.04,but nvidia does not support newer versions of ubuntu. I've just configured ; made and made install of glibc-2.33 without errors ; now I wanna know how can I tell to qemu to use this version of glibc instead of the older one.

Comment: When compiling there are usually command options used with the ./configure, --libdir=???? --installdir=???? that tells a program where to find those things to link to and install the program. Check in that file and use the location that the libc6 was installed to hopefully it was /usr/local/lib or you are in for world of trouble when you re/start your system if you overwrote the existing libraries. Even then if the local is in the path in front of the /usr/lib then they will be found first. Good luck with it.

Comment: can u give a look at this ?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320903/how-to-enable-selectively-glibc-2-33-only-for-qemu-5

Comment: Not sure if the file is not there after you are done compiling and installing it then it is never going to be.

Comment: do u see something wrong here ? ---> https://ibb.co/hLnKDCk ; maybe I missed some step...