# How to enable selectively glibc 2.33 only for qemu 5

Tags: 18.04, compiling, arm, qemu, glibc

I'm trying to virtualize windows 10 arm64 on the jetson nano where I have installed ubuntu 18.04 arm64 (I can't upgrade it to ubuntu 20.04 because nvidia does not support it). To get the best performance I've compiled the latest version of qemu like this :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local --target-list=aarch64-softmmu,arm-softmmu --enable-guest-agent --enable-vnc --enable-vnc-jpeg --enable-vnc-png --enable-kvm --enable-spice --enable-sdl --enable-gtk --enable-virglrenderer --enable-opengl
```

Windows arm64 needs qemu 5 to work great. With qemu 4.2 some features are missing. And I would also like to virtualize Android. To do that,I need to add these parameters to qemu :

```
-device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl=on,xres=1280,yres=720 -display sdl,gl=on ;
```

As u can see,it needs that all the most important features can be activated. I know that I can't use ubuntu 18.04,but nvidia does not support newer versions of ubuntu.

So I've just did :

```
./configure ; make and make install glibc-2.33 on the folder /opt/glibc-2.33
```

I didn't see errors. Actually I have two glibc configurations inside ubuntu 18.04. I would like to know how can I tell qemu to use this version of glibc instead of the older one. I ask this because as soon as the glibc compilation is ended,it still says that it's running the old version of glibc :

```
......
rm -f /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/stubs.h
/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/elf/sln /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/elf/symlink.list
rm -f /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/elf/symlink.list
test ! -x /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/elf/ldconfig || LC_ALL=C \
  /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/build-glibc-2.33/elf/ldconfig  \
/opt/glibc-2.33/lib /opt/glibc-2.33/lib
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/glibc-2.33'

root@ziomario-desktop:# ldd --version

ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.27-3ubuntu1.4) 2.27
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

I don't want that glibc 2.33 became the main option on the system,but it should be used ONLY with qemu 5,because I want to activate these parameters :

```
-device virtio-gpu-pci,virgl=on,xres=1280,yres=720 -display sdl,gl=on ;
```

thanks.

Update. I created this script :

```
isoname1=19041.804.210128-1115.VB_RELEASE_SVC_PROD1_CLIENTMULTICOMBINED_UUP_A64FRE_NETFX_IT-IT.ISO
isoname2=Windows10_InsiderPreview_Client_ARM64_en-us_21286.VHDX
virtio=virtio-win-0.1.185.iso

GLIBC=/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/glibc-2.33

GCONV_PATH=${GLIBC}/iconvdata LC_ALL=C     \
${GLIBC}/elf/ld.so.1 --library-path \
${GLIBC}:\
${GLIBC}/math:\
${GLIBC}/elf:\
${GLIBC}/dlfcn:\
${GLIBC}/nss:\
${GLIBC}/nis:\
${GLIBC}/rt:\
${GLIBC}/resolv:\
${GLIBC}/crypt:\
${GLIBC}/nptl:\
${GLIBC}/dfp \

/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64 -M virt-2.12 -enable-kvm -cpu host -smp 2 -m 2048 -device qemu-xhci -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse -drive file=/root/Scrivania/Work/win10arm/win10arm.qcow2,if=virtio -nic user,model=virtio -device usb-storage,drive=install -device usb-storage,drive=drivers -drive file="$isoname1",if=none,id=install,media=cdrom,readonly=on -drive file="$virtio",if=none,media=cdrom,readonly=on,id=drivers -bios /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/QEMU_EFI.fd -device ramfb
```

and I ran it. Unfortunately something is broken :

```
root@ziomario-desktop:# ./startvm.sh

./startvm.sh: line 7: /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/glibc-2.33/elf/ld.so.1: No such file or directory

/root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64: /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /root/Scrivania/Work/I9/win10arm/qemu/build/aarch64-softmmu/./qemu-system-aarch64)
```

As u can see below,the file `ld.so.1` is missing from within the build folder. I've looked for it in the whole system,but it isn't in any place.

[image]

do u see something wrong here ?

[image]

and then I did :

make
make install

maybe I missed some step during the compilation.

Comment: Possible:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50891548/linking-a-library-with-newer-glibc-dependencies

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. Can u refresh the page and give a look ? thanks.